# reading and writing hard disk directly in win32api like the biosdisk or absread in ms-dos

Tags: c, winapi, filesystems

I had been playing with the disk drives 12bit FAT (FAT12) and 16bit FAT(FAT16) in C language (Turbo C) which runs under the 16 bit OS MS-DOS.

I was able to manipulate sectors directly.

FAT32 was little complicated because the sectors are stored like linked list unlike other FAT lower than FAT32.

I want to read write hard disks, USB Disks directly using 32 bit C language (win32 api).

I saw [some code](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/misc/print.php/c5765) and it were using /device/ to access a disk where as in biosdisk the disks were numbered from 0 onwards i think. i was manipulating like heads, sectors, cylinders ...

Please advice on how to read write hard disks directly sector by sector or how to read write hdd in low level.

do i have to go for assembly language?

**EDIT**

one scenario why i need to directly manipulate the hard disk is i want to write a file maintaining my own FAT even hiding it from the FileSystem but marking those sectors as used. So it is just hiding a file from the other users, the operating system and even me except the program i write which can only access those files. this is just one point and the others would be just playing around. :)

Comment: The real question is why you're manipulating FAT16 disks under a 16-bit OS using an ancient compiler. The typical justification of "this is purely academic" doesn't apply here. This is almost nearly a complete waste of time.

Comment: Plus, a hard disk is not something special from the operating system's point of view, it is just a file. You can open and read/write the harddisk with the same API calls. The only problem is that a hard disk is _not quite_ a normal file, of course. So for obvious security reasons, you can only do this as administrator.

Comment: No such thing as an administrator in MS-DOS! And good thing, because I don't think Turbo C has any support for embedding manifests.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Well, the question is tagged WinAPI and the OP says explicitly "Win32 API", and the linked-to example code is for Windows NT/2k/XP. Insofar, no MS-DOS, thus no manifest = no access. Under Windows 7 with that filesystem virtualization stuff, you might even have to write a driver because quite possibly you can't directly access the disk otherwise at all (I wouldn't know why any legitimate user program should need to write to the drive directly anyway).

Comment: one scenario why i need to directly manipulate the hard disk is i want to write a file maintaining my own FAT even hiding it from the FileSystem but marking those sectors as used. So it is just hiding a file from the other users, the operating system and even me except the program i write which can only access those files. this is just one point and the others would be just playing around. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use WinAPI, then you open raw disk device using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() API (see *Physical Disks and Volumes* section there) and then use ReadFile() and WriteFile() methods to read and write data.

Note, however, that recent versions of Windows (Vista, Windows 7) restrict your access even if you are an administrator. Our RawDisk product lets you bypass these restrictions. Free non-commercial licenses are available for RawDisk.

Comment: Why would one want to bypass these very sensible restrictions? And how would you be able to do so?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there are plenty of applications and usage scenarios that need direct access to the disk or locked files (RawDisk does more than just allow direct disk access). There's nothing sensitive there if you know what you are doing. Everything is possible in kernel mode.

Comment: besides, i was thinking of a driver, function, assembly code... so that i can do exactly what i did with 16bit ms dos and the hard disk. :)